# generating DOM inside a div tag from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
                        if(response.data) {
                            $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
                                $("#fb_friends").append("<div style=\"width:150px;float:left;font-size:11px;color:White;\">");
                                $("#fb_friends").append("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"friends\" value=\"1244524\" />");
                                $("#fb_friends").append("<img src=\"http://graph.facebook.com/' + friend.id + '/picture\" alt=\"Picture\" style=\"width:24px\">");
                                $("#fb_friends").append(friend.name);
                                //alert(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
                                $("#fb_friends").append("</div>");
                            });
                        } else {
                            alert("Error!");
                        }
            });

    });
```

I also have this in my html:

```
<div id="fb_friends" style="height:280px;overflow:scroll;" >


</div>
```

I want to call this getFriends function so that it populates the HTML inside this fb_friends div I have. How do I do this?

**UPDATED** the code above doesn't work

Comment: Is this line `"<img src=\"http://graph.facebook.com/' + friend.id + '/picture\" alt=\"Picture\" style=\"width:24px\">"` working? To me it looks like you are printing "friend.id" instead o the id. Try replacing the single quotes with double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using jQuery based on the presence of the "$.each".

Try this inside of your "each" loop:

```
$("#fb_friends").append("{your html content or some DOM objects}")
```

Comment: so I am guessing I don't need a function then?

Comment: I would have to look at your code, but from what you've posted I can't see a reason to have it... other than if you are calling it after the DOM is loaded and referencing the name of the function in the load event.

Answer (score 1):

You should use DOM DocumentFragments instead of document.write. It is more performant.

Here is an interesting article about that: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery: `$('#fb_friends').html('your stuff');`

Comment: If he/she uses .html, I think it will replace whatever is in #fb_friends with each iteration... .append I think would be a better option, here.

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery, right?

```
 $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
        html = "<div [...]more html code[...] "+ friend.id + "[...]";
        $("fb_friends").append(html);
 });
```